# django models filefield upload

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I want to create a song list for eg  "movie name Titanic and it contains all its songs" but I don't know to add more than one song in a movie, can some one help me here?

Here is what I am doing

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from .models import Songs

def Songs(request):
    songs = Songs.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('profile_page.html',{'songs':songs})
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Movie(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length = 100)

class Songs(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, default= 1)
    song_title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    song_poster = models.FileField()
    song_list = models.FileField()
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^',views.Songs),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a model called `Movie`

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    // other fields as needed

class Songs(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie)
    song_title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    song_poster = models.FileField()
    song_list = models.FileField()
```

then add songs according to movie and query according to movie id

Comment: thanks , can you suggest me how to give default value to 'movie' in songs

Comment: yeah pass the id of a created movie in the foreign key as default = id of the movie in the movie table

Comment: i did but when i migrate it says 'movie_id' contains null value

Comment: I am using your models.py, Only change i made is movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, default=id)

Comment: default= 1,2 ,3 like this not id. give an integer number like 1 or 2

Comment: i updated my models.py but still when i migrate it says 'movie_id' contains null values, should i need to add IntegerField id in class Movie?

Comment: yes because there is no movie in the database with the id you passed, first you need to create a movie in the database

Comment: i tried to add movie through admin,but it showing me this  error " ProgrammingError at /admin/movie/movie/add/ "

Comment: i cant get all this, do one thing drop your database, clear all the migration files, then comment out songs from model and keep movie only, then migrate, create a movie then uncomment songs and then migrate again

Comment: not working, i am getting this error " relation "movie_movie" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "movie_movie" ("name") VALUES ('Ms Dhoni') RETUR..."

Comment: after creating the movie model did you makemigrations and then migrate?

Comment: yes i did, there was no problem but  these tables are not created in my database

Comment: thanks i reset old migrations using python manage.py migrate --fake myappname zero, and now its working, thanks you